# Set Nunit TimeoutAttribute from SpecFlow

Tags: .net, testing, nunit, integration-testing, specflow

I've written several long running end to end integration tests using SpecFlow, but they are failing due to Nunit timeouts.

Adding the [Timeout(x)] attribute to the TestFixture solves the issue, but of course gets overwritten everytime the feature is updated.

How can I remove or extend the timeout in a way that SpecFlow will respect?

Answer (score 1):

I am only getting to understand Specflow but could you implement a custom tag that could do this? Maybe you could place these at the BeforeScenario or BeforeFeature hooks?

Comment: I don't know, to be honest, and actually haven't used SpecFlow for over a year having changed employer. The new guys are just starting to bring it in though, so I might try it out soon.

Comment: [BeforeScenario("TagName)]

Answer (score 1):

How long running are we talking about? > 1 minute?
Does it have to be a full integration test?

I was reading the cucumber book - it suggested that you cheat as much as possible for your GIVEN steps to reduce the time it takes for things to run. GIVEN steps are describing the past.

I have an application form that has 5 sections to complete and can only be submitted once all sections are completed. I wanted to test some functionality that occurs on submission of the application, originally my GIVEN statements were driving the webpage through Selenium to complete all 5 sections of the form so that I could submit, I changed this to a single SQL command to set the app status for all the sections to completed. This chopped about a minute off the runtime.

The thing I was testing was the submission behaviour, the filling out the sections tests are done elsewhere.

Comment: You make a could point, but in this particular case I was slightly abusing SpecFlow as a quick way of writing end to end tests. The whole point for me was to mock out as little as possible for this particular use case.

Comment: @mavnn, I thought I was the only one who ever wrote 'could' when they meant 'good'. This is the first time I've seen it's just not me. Unless, of course, people do it a lot but I don't notice it for the same reason that I do it myself. I'm overthinking this now.

Comment: @Holf - no, I do this all the time; I refer to it as phonetic typing, as I hardly ever do it writing by hand :). Any word which sounds similar to another is fair game, and the worst bit is that spell checkers don't help!

Answer (score 1):

As @DisscCoder says,
Add a tag category to the scenario in the feature file, and add a hook that matches in a hooks class....
SpecFlow runs the before scenario code hook code for all scenarios where the string matches.

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    [Binding]
    public class Hooks1
    {               
        [BeforeScenario("LongTest")]
        public void BeforeScenario()
        {
             // Code to set Nunit timeout
        }                         
    }
}
```

---

Gherkin:

```
@LongTest
Scenario: Calc Pi to 1m digits (long)
    Given I am computing PI
    And my precision is 1 million digits
    Then my result is 3.14...
```

Comment: That doesnt work because he is looking for adding NUnit attribute "Timeout"