# Specflow ignores Visual Studio Unit Test Attribute 'Timeout'

Tags: c#, timeout, mstest, specflow, ranorex

I have an automation suite using: Mstest, Specflow and Ranorex

The WPF application under test is large and interacts with many applications like MS Word, Browsers, Sharepoint, Abobe etc. So from time to time the flow of the automation testing has a hiccup and the test hangs. This hanging time then continues until the VS/MsTest 30 minutes default timeout expires, before the application is killed and the next test can begin.

I want to decrease this wait time. There are 2 options that come up constantly in google:

1. set [TestMethod, Timeout(x)]
2. edit the Local.testsettings Test Timeout value

But neither of these seem to work under these conditions because:

1. Specflow ignores any MsTest attribute added as seen below:

   ```
       [TestMethod, Timeout(1000)]
       [When(@"I test")]
       public void WhenITest()
       {
           // some code
       }
   ```
2. "If you use a .testsettings file... does not allow you to run tests from third-party test frameworks."
   [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256991.aspx)

Therefore I need a workaround! And it seems the best way to do this is directly with Specflow hooks (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412669/set-nunit-timeoutattribute-from-specflow) in Answer 3). But to implement this into a huge framework and ensure every feature file has the tag added seems potential for human error.

Any anyone overcome a similar issue?

Comment: **"If you use a .testsettings file... does not allow you to run tests from third-party test frameworks."** How can the VS 30 min timeout kick in, if it's not possible to edit this for a 3rd party framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of curiosity, are you debugging the problematic test? As far as I know, the timeout is not taken into account by MsTest during a debugging session.

If not, you could add a timer to your test initialization, set to the timeout value you wish. To add to Sam Holder's answer, you could have (with MsTest syntax):

```
    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer(FailTheTest, null, 0, timeoutValue);            
    }

    private void FailTheTest(object state)
    {
        Assert.Fail("Insert here your timeout message");
    }
```

Be sure to correctly clean up your test environment afterwards, so as not to leave documents, or service calls hanging.

Comment: You were correct in that I needed to build my project as Release. I had a couple of errors to resolve with my project configuration to get a successful build. Now I have now tested the .testSettings Timeout value and it is working. Your help is most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add it to every feature file if you are happy to add it to all tests by default. Just add a `[BeforeScenario]` with no tag and insert your additional code in there and it will be added to every test.

You can also 'opt-out' some tests by checking if the opt out tag is present and not executing the code in that case:

```
[BeforeScenario()]
public static void BeforeWebScenario()
{
    if(!ScenarioContext.Current.ScenarioInfo.Tags.Contains("noReducedTimeout"))
        AddReducedTimeout;
}
```

I'm not sure how you will add the MSTest timeout attribute to your test, but as you seem to think the other answer provides that information then I'll leave that as an exercise for the student.

If this doesn't work then you should be able to do this by adding a plugin for specflow which will allow the unit test generator to augment the generated tests with this timeout. Unfortunately there is not a great deal of detail on how to do this out there, but [this blog post](http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2013/04/creating-custom-unit-test-generator.html) should point you in the right direction.

If you do write a plugin, writing one that adds any attributes on the parent step definition could be generically useful :)

Comment: Thanks for your response Sam Holder. In hindsight the idea of a [BeforeScenario] wont work because what I really need is a [DuringScenario], which obviously doesn't exist in Specflow. I don't have code prepared and I don't believe my coding is strong enough to create my own plugin. I'm very surprised that there is not a more straight-forward way to achieve this.

Comment: Creating a plugin isn't that difficult. I have a similar plugin which I'm writing which adds a few NCrunch specific attributes to the tests. I'll see if this might be co-opted to add timeouts. In the meantime another option is to generate the tests using NCunch

Comment: Why don't you add a timer to your BeforeScenario which calls `Assert.Fail()` if the scenario tag is set to reduced timeout?

Comment: @Keysharpener This might help, and is probably worth trying, but MSTest might still be sat waiting for a method to return until the test times out on the main thread.  And why not add it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the option 2 above eventually worked for me:
* edit the Local.testsettings Test Timeout value

The fix was that I needed to specify the Local.testsettings as an additional parameter in the TeamCity Build Steps.

Example:
TeamCity - Build Step

- Runner Type = MsTest
- List assembly files = /MyProject/UITests.dll
- Additional command line parameters = **/testsettings:"Trunk/Tests/AutomationTests/ProjectName/local.testsettings"**